# Splitting CreateView form into multiple pieces / Targeting individual fields

Tags: django

Is there a fast way to split a form, created by Django's `CreateView` cbv, into two or more parts? I'm trying to style two halves of a form differently via CSS. Similarly, can each of the fields/labels that are generated by the `CreateView` be individually targeted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can handle the form in the template like any other form. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template) here about customizing forms. Below is the code example with `other-class` added to two of the fields. You can customize the html however you need to.

```
<form action="/contact/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.subject.errors }}
        <label for="id_subject">Email subject:</label>
        {{ form.subject }}
    </div>
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.message.errors }}
        <label for="id_message">Your message:</label>
        {{ form.message }}
    </div>
    <div class="fieldWrapper other-class">
        {{ form.sender.errors }}
        <label for="id_sender">Your email address:</label>
        {{ form.sender }}
    </div>
    <div class="fieldWrapper other-class">
        {{ form.cc_myself.errors }}
        <label for="id_cc_myself">CC yourself?</label>
        {{ form.cc_myself }}
    </div>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send message" /></p>
</form>
```